# How do i print/show a result from a php query (mysqli) in a HTML page

Tags: php, html

I've searched hard to find a way to print the query of the code above into a HTML part, but i don't find anything. I saw that is possible to present the result by a HTML table using the `fetch_assoc()` of php. Below is the code, and on a global view the code is fine, because i test it on a full php page. But i need a solution to put it in HTML. Am i trying an impossible thing?

```
<?php
    require_once('connconf.php'); 
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $bdname) or die ('Connection Error');
    $sqlquery = "select ID_Vote from Votes where ID_Player = '1'"; 
    if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery)) {
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo $rowcount;   //this is the value i want to publish on a HTML <label>
    }
?>
```

Comment: No not impossible, you are quiet a way from your goal though. You just need to read a book or an online tutorial about PHP and HTML and how they fit together. [Try starting here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)

Comment: Further down on the same page... outside of that PHP block... `<label><?php echo $rowcount ?></label>`

Comment: *upful* i tried what you answer with and without ";" And never forgetting the "}" beetween "$rowcount" and "?>" but it keeps showing nothing.

*RiggsFolly* I think the problem here is not ignorance about the syntax, i've already tried too many ways, but seems that the problem is other thing.

    
   

                   (....)
                
               if($resposta = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery))
       {
                  $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($resposta);
             ?>
      
         <label>    <?php echo $rowcount; }  ?>   </ label>

Comment: @volkel Comments aren't really meant for blocks of code. If you're trying to show a different version, edit your question (the edit "button" is below the tags). That being said, is ID_Player a numeric field in the database? If so, comparing it to a string is wrong.

Comment: Yes @TiesonT. ID_Player is an Int field, does it change anything?

Comment: Well, run the query directly against the database, with and without quotes, and find out.

Comment: But the query is ok, iv'e already try the code in a full php page and it shows what is expected to show, but i need the result to be presentend in html, and thats what is bothering me, because something is not well, and i dont know what.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the results in a table you could do like this:

```
print "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print "<tr><td>".$row['ID_Vote']."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

The same goes if you just want to print the amount of rows:

```
print "<table>";
print "<tr><td>".$rowcount."</td></tr>";
print "</table>";
```

Another way of doing it could be to end php:

```
<?
// Some code
?>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><?=$rowcount;?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<?
// More php
?>
```

You can have a read [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php)

Comment: hello and thanks for the answer. I tried the three ways, but it keeps not showing the result.. i dont know what to do, the problem should be other thing.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the solution to my problem, all the query was ok like i said. But the extension of my webpage was .HTML and when i change it to .php it worked. Now i got the website running with HTML and php code using a .php extension instead .html

Thanks for your attention.